# Ctags Can't tag SDL/SDL2 functions

Tags: sdl, sdl-2, ctags, universal-ctags

Using Ctag to jump to function decleration. Works fine for everything but not with SDL functions.

I used `ctags -R .` command to generate the tagfile in `/usr/include/` file to generate tag file. And added `set tags+=/usr/include/tags` to `.vimrc` file so that vim can find and use it.

Which works fine for everything else and SDL `struct` and `definde` but can't find any function.

Like `SDL2/SDL_render.h` file there are a lot of `struct` and `function` but in the tag file there are only found the `struct`ure's and `function`'s.
[see the ctag generated tag here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKXVj.jpg)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59P8t.jpg)

So, How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems the command
`ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extras=+q .`
running in `/usr/include/` folder fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As Noman wrote, `--c++-kinds=+p` is needed.
In addition, you may need to pass `-I DECLSPEC -I SDLCALL`

As far as reading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LuaDist/sdl/master/include/SDL_render.h, macros that ctags doesn't know how to handle it are used in the header file. The options (`-I`) are the hints for ctags.